# Identifying dates that falls in the same month, day period across years

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've got a whole list of dates. I need to find out which dates fall within the same range (day and month) as my stipulated "Start Date" and "End Date" for each of the years.

For e.g. for Start Date:2/12/2004, End Date: 31/1/2005, dates falling between 2/12/2000 and 31/1/2001, 2/12/2001 and 31/1/2002, 2/12/2001 and 31/1/2002 etc should be flagged out as "Valid".

Currently I use an upper/lower limit and then test if the Date falling within the range.

Excel Formulas:

Upper: =DATE(YEAR(Date),MONTH(Test),DAY(Test)+Look Back Period)

Lower: =DATE(YEAR(Date),MONTH(Test),DAY(Test)-Look Back Period)

Valid: =IF(AND(Date<=Upper,Date>=Lower),1,0)

```
Test                    1/1/2005
Look Back Period (Days) 30
Start Date              2/12/2004 (=Test + Look Back Period)
End Date                31/1/2005 (=Test - Look Back Period)


    Date        Upper       Lower       Valid
    04/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    05/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    06/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    07/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    10/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    11/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    12/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    13/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    14/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    17/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    18/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    19/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    20/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    21/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    24/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    25/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    26/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    27/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    28/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    31/01/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   1
    01/02/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    02/02/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    03/02/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    04/02/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    07/02/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    .
    .
    .
    30/11/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    01/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0
    04/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    05/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    06/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    07/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    08/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    11/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    12/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    13/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    14/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    15/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    18/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    19/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    20/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    21/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    22/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    25/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    26/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    27/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    28/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    29/12/2000  31/1/2000   2/12/1999   0 <-- :(
    01/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    02/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    03/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    04/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    05/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    08/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    09/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    10/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
    11/01/2001  31/1/2001   2/12/2000   1
```

The formula works fine as long as the periods do not cross between years. However, in the event the Upper and Lower limit cross through between 2 different years, the Valid formula will exclude the previous year's values.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This looks like a good example for a Segment Tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree Are you familiar with algorithms and VBA?

Comment: yep. I can code a solution with vba. however, for the legacy sake of this sheet (which is more likely than not be passed down to someone else), i would prefer an excel formula solution to this.

Comment: Can you give us an example of one that doesn't work plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with formulas, set up two more helper columns

```
lower1: =DATE(YEAR(Date)-1,MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate))
upper1: =C8+2*LookBack
Lower2: =DATE(YEAR(Date),MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate))
Upper2: =Lower2+2*LookBack

valid:  =IF(OR(AND(Date>=lower1,Date<=upper1),AND(Date>=Lower2,Date<=Upper2)),1,0)
```

All we are doing is setting up two sets of bounds. Relative to `Date`, one starts with the previous year; the other starts with the current year.  Then check `Date` to see if it falls within either set.

For appearances, there is no requirement that the bounds columns be visible, or even that they be contiguous with the `Date` and `valid` columns.

[image]

Comment: I was working on a formula that doesn't use additional helper columns (I often take that for a challenge :P), but +1 for this solution is very neat and I love the fact that it is readable and understandable :)

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you.  I thought the fact that he both wants an Excel solution and will be passing this down to others was in favor of readability vs compactness.

Comment: There is no shame in using helper columns. In fact, in most projects I would prefer people use helper columns because it makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot, explain, audit, and debug later on. Super-formulas are awful on all of those counts.

Comment: thank you so much! your solution works perfectly! i tend to prefer to squeeze everything into a single formula as well, but in this case, i think i just confused myself. did not think of adding an additional parameter for the previous year as well. great solution! @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @RonRosenfeld one minor edit though. your lower and upper formula is a little mixed up. cheerios!

Comment: @adam Thanks.  Sorted.